# Acceder a una constante dentro de un objeto en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy creando un método de eventos personalizado, para hacerlo debo crear los tipos de evento como constantes. Mi duda es cómo acceder a una constante dentro de un objeto.

Ejemplo:

```
var EventManager=function() {
    const EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN = "EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN";
};
```

desde afuera quiero acceder a `EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN`. 
Algo así:

```
var eventManager = new EventManager();
console.log(eventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN );
```

tampoco puedo acceder asi

```
console.log(EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN );
```

Comment: tenes que declarar tu constante dentro de tu función?? porque podrías declararla fuera de tu función como global y utilizar dentro de la función

Comment: si, quiero declararla dentro de la funcion porque en realidad es un objeto lo manejo como una clase, la duda que tengo es como accedo  a ellas luego, como ejemplo, asi lo accederia si fuese una variable comun
eventManager.variable
pero no responde en el caso de ser constante

Answer (score 4):

Puedes hacer esto:

```
var EventManager = function(){
  //codigo
}

EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN = 'EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN';

//y lo podrías usar así:
var eManager = new EventManager();
EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN;
```

La respuesta de @josego te podría funcionar también.

```
//De esta manera los objetos que se definan tendrán la propiedad 'EVENTS' con los tipos de eventos y serán inmutables 
var EventManager = function(){
    var events = {
        EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN: 'EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN'
    };
    this.EVENTS = Object.freeze( events );
};
//
var eventManaget = new EventManager();
eventManager.EVENTS.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN;  //'EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN'
```

O podrías retornar un objeto 'congelado' con Object.freeze

```
var EventManager = function(){
    var eventManager = function(){
        this.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN = 'EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN';
    };
    return Object.freeze( new eventManager() );
};
var eventManager = new EventManager();
eventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN; //   'EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN'
```

Comment: Esta solución define una propiedad común y corriente, y no una constate (solo lectura).

Comment: @Mariano es muy cierto lo que dice Marcos Gallardo. No soluciona el tema de la constante. Es una variable EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN = 'EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN';

Comment: ☝☝☝ @ftorres es el autor, yo sólo corregí un detalle de la respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Hasta donde yo se no se puede hacer directamente declarar dentro de la función una constante y utilizar fuera de la función. Lo que si podes hacer algo como lo que muestro abajo. Con Object.freeze(miConstante) se queda como constante y si le queres asignar nuevos valores, no lo toma.

```
class miConstante {};
miConstante.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN = "EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN";
Object.freeze(miConstante);

console.log("Valor de la constante: ", miConstante.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN );

// NO cambia el valor de la constante.
miConstante.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN = "Hola";
console.log("CAmbiar valor de la constante: ", miConstante.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN );
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: si me sirve puedo usarlo asi, de todos modos es por orden el codigo es mio y lo voy a usar yo mismo pero queria hacerlo lo mas ordenado posible, muchas gracias!

Comment: @Pablo Por el tema del orden, podrías definir una forma de programar e usar estándares como que todas las constantes estén en mayúsculas y definí siempre al principio de tu script. Si te sirve la respuesta podrías ponerlo como solucionado. Gracias

Comment: @Pablo si llegaste a solucionar, podrías poner la respuesta que te sirvió. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/defineProperty) (`IE9+`): Este método permite añadir o modificar una propiedad en un objeto. Indicando `writable: false`, la propiedad se creara de solo lectura.

```js
var EventManager = function(){
  //codigo
}

Object.defineProperty(EventManager, 'EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
  value: 1
});

console.log(EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN);
EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN = 2;
console.log(EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN);
```

- **ES6**: se pueden crear variables de solo lectura (*constantes*) usando la palabra clave [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/const).

  ```
  const EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN = 1;
  ```

  > Lamentablemente este método no se puede usar para declarar contantes como propiedad de objeto.

  Una forma de conseguir un resultado similar al propuesto en la pregunta, es usando la [sintaxis `get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/get) combinada con [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Classes/static).

```js
class EventManager {

  static get EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN() { return 1; }
}

console.log(EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN);
try {
 EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN = 2;
} catch(e) {
  console.log('ERROR!');
}
console.log(EventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN);
```

Answer (score 2):

Una opción que tienes es congelar el objeto [como sugiere josego](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/39844/250) usando [`Object.freeze(variable)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/freeze). En ese enlace se explica que:

> El método **`Object.freeze()`** congela un objeto: es decir, previene que nuevas propiedades sean agregadas; privene que las propiedades existentes sean eliminadas; y previene que las propiedades existentes, o su capacidad de enumeración, configuración, o escritura. de ser cambiadas. En escencia el objeto es hecho efectivamente inmutable. El método regresa el objeto congelado.

Lo que podrías hacer es definir tu objeto con las constantes que necesites y entonces congelarlo. Lo malo de esto es que se congelarán TODAS las variables, no sólo las que quieres que sean constantes. Las funciones seguirían funcionando normalmente, entonces lo que podrias hacer es definir todo en un objeto y añadirle un "constructor" que lo congele y lo devuelva (para que se pueda estandarizar y usar del mismo modo con más de una variable).

Aquí dejo un ejemplo:

```js
var miObjeto = {
  // aquí irían las constantes
  EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN: "EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN",
 
  // aquí puedes poner funciones

  // el "constructor" que congelará y devolverá el objeto 
  constructor: function() {
    Object.freeze(this);
    return this;
  }
}

var em = miObjeto.constructor();
console.log(em.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN);

em.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN = "Un texto diferente";
console.log(em.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN);
```

O si lo quieres dejar en la forma de una función como lo tenías al principio, podrías hacer algo parecido a esto:

```js
function EventManager() {

    const obj = {
      EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN: "EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN"
    };
    
    return Object.freeze(obj);
  
}

var em = new EventManager();
console.log(em.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN);

em.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN = 12;
console.log(em.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN);
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar los métodos *privileged* de la siguiente manera:

**Private**

```
function Constructor(value) {
   var that = this;
   var membername = value;
   var membername = function membername() {...};
}
```

**Privileged**

```
function Constructor(value) {
   var that = this;
   const memberName = value;
   this.methodMemberName = function () { return memberName; };
}
```

Así de la siguiente forma para tu ejemplo:

```js
var EventManager = function(){
 const EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN  = "EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN";
    this.getEventOnUserLogin = function(){
       return EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN;
    }
    this.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN = function(){
       return EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN;
    } 
}

var eventManager = new EventManager();

console.log(eventManager.EVENT_ON_USER_LOGIN());
console.log(eventManager.getEventOnUserLogin());
```

En mi caso prefiero que el evento se llame *getEventOnUserLogin*.

Puedes encontrar más información en el siguiente enlace
http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html